# Create dynamic parameters with pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

I am attempting to test various endpoints of my REST API. Some of the end points take values that are provided by other end points. For example:

- Query `/locations` to get a list of available locations and if they are enabled
- Query `/inventory?loc_id=<id>` and pass in a location ID to get a list of inventory at specific location
- Query `/inventory/<id>/details` to get a list of attributes associated with one particular inventory ID

In my tests, I want to walk this entire work flow (checking specific attributes of inventory items at specific locations). Normally, I'd build a pytest function with a couple `@parameterize` decorators, but in this case, I don't know all the IDs ahead of time.

What I'd normally do:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('location', ['1', '2', '3', 'HQ'])
@pytest.mark.parametrize('inventory_id', [1, 2, 3])
def test_things(location, inventory_id):
    # Call /inventory/inventory_id/details and check attributes
```

That second line is a problem because I don't know the `inventory_id`s without calling `/inventory` first. It's also entirely possible that the `inventory_id` isn't available at a specific location.

What I'd like to do:

```
Query /location to build a list of IDs to add to the first parameterize line
Query `/inventory?loc_id=<id>` and build a list of IDs to pass to the second parameterize line
```

How can I dynamically build these lines?

Comment: *but in this case, I don't know all the IDs ahead of time*  <--  that means you're not setting up your fixtures properly.  The inventory ids can and should be under your control in test setup.  Once you fix that problem, this problem will go away.

Comment: This particular test is ensuring all new items are set up properly in the database prior to production. This isn't a unit test, but more of a pre-production deployment test.

Comment: Don't bother with a parametrize decorator then.  Just make a query to get inventory ids inside the test, and use plain old for-loops.

Answer (score 10):

If it's really the case that you want to test each location with each inventory_id you can just calculate those lists ahead of test

```py
def get_locations_list(...):
    locations = []
    # query locations
    ...
    return locations

LOCATIONS = get_locations_list()
INVENTORY_IDS = get_inventory_ids()

@pytest.mark.parametrize('location', LOCATIONS)
@pytest.mark.parametrize('inventory_id', INVENTORY_IDS)
def test_things(location, inventory_id):
    # test stuff
```

If inventory ids depend on location then you can prepare list of tuples:

```py
def get_locations_and_ids():
    list_of_tuples = []
    ...
    for location in locations:
        ids = ...
        for id in ids:
            list_of_tuples.append( (location, id) )
    return list_of_tuples

LIST_OF_TUPLES = get_locations_and_ids()

@pytest.mark.parametrize(('location', 'inventory_id'), LIST_OF_TUPLES)
def test_things(location, inventory_id):
    # ...
```

You can also use pytest-generate-tests pattern as described in:

https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html#basic-pytest-generate-tests-example

Comment: Link is broken. https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/parametrize.html?highlight=parameters is the nearest one

Comment: Can the function `get_locations_and_ids()` get a fixture as argument, for example `get_locations_and_ids(base_path)` ?

Answer (score -1):

You can try pytest.fixtures to create context for your test check out the documentation [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html)

In this case you can generate any object/value that you need
for example:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture 
def inventory_id():
    return InventoryObject.id
```

Other Option is to use the [vcrpy](https://github.com/kevin1024/vcrpy) package. This allow you to record a real HTTP call and save it in a file.