# reading custom options in pytest and loading data based on them

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, pytest-fixtures

I have a json file which has multiple json objects each json object looks like
{ test:"test1",tags:['tag1','tag2']
I added a command line option for including and excluding this tags wether to be loaded or not
I'm loading this json file to pytest based on the tags that are given from cli

how do I load this data and then parametric this test accordingly?

if I loaded 12 items into the list after filtering based on tags how do I parametrize them into 12 tests

and I'm able to read the options only through a fixture
how do I parametric the data returned by a fixture

right now I have

```
def loaded data(include_tags,exclude_tags,filename):
    
    data=json.load(filename)

    if include_tags or exclude_tags:    
        filtered_data = []    
  
        include_tags = set(include_tags.split(',')) if include_tags else None    
        exclude_tags = set(exclude_tags.split(',')) if exclude_tags else None    
  
        for ele in data:    
            tags = set(ele[VIRTUAL_COACH_TAG])    
  
            if include_tags and not tags.intersection(include_tags):    
                continue    
            if exclude_tags and tags.intersection(exclude_tags):    
                continue    
  
            filtered_data.append(ele)    
  
        data = filtered_data    
  
    logger.info("returning data %s", len(data))    
    return fd, data

@pytest.fixture()
def data():
    include_tags=request.config.getoption("--include_tags")
    exclude_tags=request.config.getoption("--exclude_tags")
    return loaded_data(include_tags,exclude_tags,filename)
```

now I want to parametrize the data returned by data fixture

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create dynamic parameters with pytest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45843289/create-dynamic-parameters-with-pytest)